# Passing multiple values for a single parameter from SSRS to hive

Tags: reporting-services, hive

[Creating a concatenated string in SSRS with values enclosed in single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247552/creating-a-concatenated-string-in-ssrs-with-values-enclosed-in-single-quotes/49993227#49993227)

Any answers to the above question?. I am struck with the same problem:

The query from SSRS side is:

```
select *
from xyz.test_table1
where f1 in (?)
```

Datasource for me in this case is a hive table. User selection on the parameter is a multivalued parameter which is what I expect to be substituted as:

```
where in ('value1','value2')
```

when query is executed. But when looked at the query execution on the hive side, it comes as:

```
where in ('value1,value2')
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: What is your exact problem?  What format *exactly* are you trying to pass your values in, to what and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a concatenated string in SSRS with values enclosed in single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247552/creating-a-concatenated-string-in-ssrs-with-values-enclosed-in-single-quotes)

Comment: The query from SSRS side is like select * from xyz.test_table1 where f1 in (?). Datasource for me in this case is a hive table. User selection on the parameter is a multivalued parameter which is what I expect to be substituted as where in ('value1','value2') when query is executed. But when looked at the query execution on the hive side, it comes as where in ('value1,value2). How could I solve this?

Comment: * But when looked at the query execution on the hive side, it comes as where in ('value1,value2')

Comment: Personally I am not too familiar with Hive, especially when queried from SSRS.  Does your dataset script need to be written in Hive Query Language?

Comment: Yes. Dave. But as far this query goes, it is same as SQL. However, I figured out the solution to this. If you give the query as an expression like this, it works. ="select * from xyz.test_table1 where f1 in ('"&Join(Parameters!param.Value,"','")&"')"

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Common+Table+Expression), it seems Hive Query Language supports Common Table Expressions.

Consequently, something similar to the following *should* work:

```
declare @str nvarchar(4000) = ?;        -- String to split.

with n(n) as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1)

     -- Select the same number of rows as characters in @str as incremental row numbers.
     -- Cross joins increase exponentially to a max possible 10,000 rows to cover largest @str length.
  ,t(t)   as (select top (select len(isnull(@str,'')) a) row_number() over (order by (select null)) from n n1,n n2,n n3,n n4)

     -- Return the position of every value that follows the specified delimiter.
  ,s(s)   as (select 1 union all select t+1 from t where substring(isnull(@str,''),t,1) = ',')

     -- Return the start and length of every value, to use in the SUBSTRING function.
     -- ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the last value where there is no delimiter at the end of the string.
  ,l(s,l) as (select s,isnull(nullif(charindex(',',isnull(@str,''),s),0)-s,4000) from s)

     -- Return each individual value in the delimited string along with it's position.
  ,v      as (select row_number() over(order by s) as rn
                    ,substring(@str,s,l) as item
              from l
             )
select *
from v
    join xyz.test_table1 as t
        on v.v = t.f1
```

---

If you rather understandably don't want this rigamarole in all of your datasets, you would need to encapsulate this logic into whatever the Hive equivalent of a SQL Server table-valued parameter is, perhaps a [UDTF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DeveloperGuide+UDTF)?

In SQL Server, the function would be defined as follows:

```
create function [dbo].[fn_StringSplit4k]
(
  @str nvarchar(4000) = ' '        -- String to split.
 ,@delimiter as nvarchar(1) = ','  -- Delimiting value to split on.
 ,@num as int = null               -- Which value to return.
)
returns table
as
return
     -- Start tally table with 10 rows.
 with n(n)   as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1)

     -- Select the same number of rows as characters in @str as incremental row numbers.
     -- Cross joins increase exponentially to a max possible 10,000 rows to cover largest @str length.
  ,t(t)   as (select top (select len(isnull(@str,'')) a) row_number() over (order by (select null)) from n n1,n n2,n n3,n n4)

     -- Return the position of every value that follows the specified delimiter.
  ,s(s)   as (select 1 union all select t+1 from t where substring(isnull(@str,''),t,1) = @delimiter)

     -- Return the start and length of every value, to use in the SUBSTRING function.
     -- ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the last value where there is no delimiter at the end of the string.
  ,l(s,l) as (select s,isnull(nullif(charindex(@delimiter,isnull(@str,''),s),0)-s,4000) from s)

 select rn
          ,item
 from(select row_number() over(order by s) as rn
    ,substring(@str,s,l) as item
  from l
  ) a
 where rn = @num
  or @num is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Posting the answer for other users.

Provide the query(under Query in SSRS) as an expression like below:

="select * from xyz.test_table1 where f1 in ('"&Join(Parameters!param.Value,"','")&"')"

The above string manipulation translates to:

select * from xyz.test_table1 where f1 in ('value1','value2')

Note: value1, value2 here are the values from user selected multivalue parameter